# Is it allowed to use "Magento" in a domain?

Tags: magento2, magento-1

I tried to find information about it, but could not find anything specific ... so, is it allowed to have domains like "magento.pro" or "my-magento-agency.com"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to a lawyer familiar with the UDRP (Uniform Domain-Name Dispute-Resolution Policy).

> You need to talk to a lawyer familiar with the UDRP (Uniform
> Domain-Name Dispute-Resolution Policy).
>
> There is no simple answer to this question, as it will depend on
> (among other things) what you will be doing with the domain name. If
> your site will be in some sense competing with Magento, that's
> trouble. If your site could be confused with Magento (or appears to
> be somehow official or associated with Magento), that's trouble.
>
> But suppose your website is 'Magentotutor.com' and it exists to teach
> people how to use Magento, and it doesn't look like Magento, and it
> has a clear and obvious disclaimer that it is unofficial and not
> affiliated with Magento, then you'd be on safer grounds.
>
> So, as I said, talk to a lawyer. But also be serious about assessing
> the business case for doing this in the first place.

Source: Jimmy Wales for [a similar question](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-run-a-website-with-Facebook-like-domain-names) on quora.com'.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to know if its really ok...maybe Adobe just did not spoit that one Domain. I looked through their policies, found nothing though.

Comment: I would be careful about giving legal advice.

Comment: @sv3n I total agree with you, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I really appreciated that!